# Running time of graph algorithm

Tags: time-complexity

I have a question about the calculation of running time of the below algorithm 
I am not sure of my answer and I would like to check the correct answer

```
Algorithm Unknown(G)
Input: A weighted graph with n vertices, and m edges
Output: ?????
    P ← create array of size n to to referenced by vertix id number (id[u])
    Q ← create array of size n to to referenced by vertix id number.
    for each u ∈ G.vertices() do
        Q[id(u)] ← null
    for each v ∈ G.vertices() do
        for each u  G.vertices() do
            if G.areAdjacent(u,v) then
                P[id(u)] ← -∞
        for each u ∈ G.vertices() do
            for each e ∈ G.incidentEdges(u) do
                z ← G.opposite(u,e)
                if G.valueAt(e) > P[id(z)] then
                    P[id(z)] ← valueAt(e)
                    Q[id(z)] ← e
    return Q
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you post your answer as well?

Comment: you also need to know the (worst case?) time complexity of areAdjacent, which could be O(1) or O(m), depending on how the graph is implemented.